# VBA - open excel, find and replace, delete row, save as csv

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I am trying to write a program in VBA so that I can remotely manipulate an excel file from SAS (a statistical programming software). I want the program to accomplish the following:

1. open the specified excel file
2. find and replace all blanks in the header row with nothing (e.g., "Test Name" become "TestName")
3. delete the second row if first cell in row (i.e., A2) is blank
4. save the file as a csv

I do not know VBA, have dabbled with it a little, know some other programming languages, and have tried to piece this together. I stole some code to make 1 and 4 work. I cannot get 2 and 3 to work. This is what I have:

#### I put the following in SAS to call the vba program -

```
x 'cd C:\Location';/*change to location of VBS file*/
x "vbsprogram.vbs inputfile.xls outputfile.csv";
```

#### The VBA Program -

```
'1 - Open the specified excel file
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))

'2 - Find and Replace
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="* *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

'3 - Delete second row if blank
oBook.Cell("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

'4 - Save as csv
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Any assistance pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Also, is there a way to select all data in row 1 as the range (in part 2) and not have to specify a set range of cells?

Comment: If there is any problem with this code, or you just looking for the explanation on how it works? Please be specific. Thanks.

Comment: Part 2 and 3 of this code don't work. I pieced them together from what I could find and what I know of programming, but they are definitely missing things because I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
'2:   - Find and Replace
oBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2,1).EntireRow.Replace " ", ""

'3 - Delete second row if blank
If oExcel.CountA(oBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2,1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
  oBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2,1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Cells'" Code: 800A01B6. And I'm afraid I don't know enough to start troubleshooting this.

Comment: Thanks a million! Two quick fixes: (1) I wanted to do the find and replace in the first row so it should be "oBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)..."; and (2) I only need to check the first cell in row 2 because the rest of it contains data. After I removed .EntireRow from the first part of the statement everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, you need to fix statement (2) and (3) of the original code, and also concatenate the values of all cells in row 1. You can achieve this by looping through each cell in 2 Range objects corresponding to rows 1 and 2. General syntax for that operation in Excel VBA (source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is shown in the following sample code snippet:

```
Sub FormatRow1()
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G1").Cells
        if (c.Value) = {condition} then do something.
    Next
End Sub
```

FYI: string concatenation in Excel VBA performed with `&` operator. Also, you should use `Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )` and `Range(range).EntireRow.Delete` VBA operators to complete the task.

Comment: Any chance you could make that more specific to my code? I'm not following exactly... c.Value refers to the entire cell contents, right? So for statement (2) would I have something along the lines of:     For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G1").Cells      Replace (c, " ", "")      Next.      And for statement (3) why would I search through a range when I only need to check the value in one cell (the first cell in row 2, A2)? Sorry for my lack of vision with this.

Comment: Correct: looping applies to the statement (2). For the statement (3) just check the value of that critical cell you have mentioned ("A2") and apply EntireRow.Delete if condition is met.

Comment: I never got this solution to work with my code (I'm not knowledgeable enough to put it into practice effectively), but thanks for the assistance!